# Issue with Carbon not equal when it should be

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Having an issue where literal comparing of 2 Carbon objects are not equal, and I'm not sure why, I have posted my tinker session below to show the problem;

```
>>> $t = Carbon\Carbon::today()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1548025200 {#3026
     date: 2019-01-21 00:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+01:00),
   }
>>> $f = Carbon\Carbon::parse('21-01-2019 10:02:01')->startOfDay()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1548025200 {#3035
     date: 2019-01-21 00:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+01:00),
   }
>>> $f === $t
=> false
>>> $f == $t
=> true
>>> echo $t
2019-01-21 00:00:00⏎
>>> echo $f
2019-01-21 00:00:00⏎
>>>
```

Just wondering why `$f === $t` is false,

Thanks for anyone that can help!

Also even using `today()` for both returns false; (But in case either of these have different solutions, the first example is more applicable to my issue)

```
>>> $t = Carbon\Carbon::today()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1548025200 {#3033
     date: 2019-01-21 00:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+01:00),
   }
>>> $f = Carbon\Carbon::today()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1548025200 {#3038
     date: 2019-01-21 00:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+01:00),
   }
>>> $f === $t
=> false
>>> $f == $t
=> true
```

Comment: Manual maybe http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php?

Comment: This is how the `===` operator works for objects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589748/157957), and this sentence in the manual: "When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class."

Comment: I did read the manual, but I misread/understood identical classes matching due to the duplicating the object example ($p = $o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Carbon's comparison functions](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) to avoid those issues.

Comment: Well, in this case you don't avoid an issue, because there is no issue in checking 2 objects equality with the identity operator.. as the result will be always true if they are both refering to the same instance or false otherwise...

Comment: it's fine for my purpose, I just did `->diffInDays === 0`, thanks